# Ephemeral volume limit making pod errored out

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, persistent-volumes

I'm working on the task where I want to limit the Ephemeral volume to a certain Gi.
This is my deployment configuration file.
`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vol
  namespace: namespace1
  labels:
    app: vol
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vol
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vol
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: vol
          image: <my-image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          resources:
            limits:
              ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ephemeral
              mountPath: "/volume"
      volumes:
        - name: ephemeral
          emptyDir: {}
```

`

The expected behaviour is when the volume limit is met it should evict the pod, which is happening as expected.

The only problem I have is after the default termination grace period the pod is getting into an error state with a warning `ExceededGracePeriod`. Now, I have one pod running and one error in my deployment.

I have tried solutions like increased the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`, tried to use `preStop` hook, settings limit on `emptyDir: {}` as well but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: Have you tried that with 2 replicas?

Comment: No, I haven't. This is only for one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the ephemeral storage limit to  2Gi ephemeral storage. This might resolve your error. Refer to this [doc](https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/3/dev_guide/compute_resources.html) for quotas and [limit ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) of ephemeral storage. In kubernetes documentation you can find more details how Ephemeral storage consumption management works [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-emphemeralstorage-consumption).